# Interpreting cachegrind Ir count for function declaration lines

Tags: c++, profiling, kcachegrind, cachegrind

I have cachegrind line-by-line counts for two similar functions, used exactly the same way.  The Ir counts for the function declaration lines (void f(...)) are very different: 999,999,993 for one and only 284 for the other.  What does this mean?